# What was the speed limitations for droop nose on the Concorde?

Tags: concorde

Lowering gears or extending flaps comes with limitations. Given the answer of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/62559/what-were-the-concordes-emergency-procedures-for-an-uncommanded-droop-nose-exte) I suppose the limit speed for full nose down is about 325 kt. My question is: what were the limit for all positions (visor down but nose full up, nose in take off position, nose in landing position, any other position I don't know)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the systems chapter on the nose, it turns out a *dual* uplock failure would limit the drop to 5° (see updated answer). If it is just one uplock that failed, the nose/visor should hold, but reducing the speed is out of caution.

As for the speed limits, here they are from the aircraft limitations section of the manual:

[image]

Comment: Was the prohibition on nose/visor operation below 500 ft AGL a result of the change in pitching tendency caused thereby?